# Measure $\mu_f$ for function $f(x)=x^2$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X=[0,1]$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure. Describe the measure $\mu_f$ for the function $f(x)=x^2$.

By definition of $\mu_f$: For any Borel subset $A\subseteq R$, we have $$\mu_f(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A)) = \mu(\{x\in[0,1]\mid x^2\in A\})$$

Is there anything that can/should be said about $\mu_f$? I'm not sure because of the vague problem statement.

Comment: $\mu(A) \leq \mu_f(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could say that
$$
\mu_f((a,b]) = \sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a}
$$
for any interval $(a,b] \subset [0,1]$; or that
$$
\mu_f(A) = \int_A \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx
$$
for any Borel set $A \subset [0,1]$?

Comment: I can see the first one. Where does the second one come from?

Comment: The second one holds because it is true for all intervals $(a,b]$; and hence by uniqueness of the extension, it holds for all Borel sets.

Comment: Wait, actually isn't the first one $\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}$ rather than $b^2-a^2$?

Comment: @PJMiller : Yes, of course it is. I am used to $\mu_f$ defined the other way around (See Folland's book for instance). Hence the confusion. My apologies :)

Comment: Prahlad, interesting to know that some books define $\mu_f$ the other way around (I guess that's too common on mathematics...). Thank you :)